# readonly option is set add to ! override - Windows 8.1

Tags: vim

I was trying to change the `colorscheme` in `vimrc`. But, when I try to say, I get the following error `readonly option is set add to ! override`, provided that I'm using `Windows 8.1`. How can I fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, can you force the write with `:w!`, or does that fail? Do you have created your own `.vimrc` in your user's directory, or do you reuse the template under Vim's install directory?

Comment: @IngoKarkat. Thanks for your reply. I'm using the `.vimrc` that comes with Vim. Regarding `:w!`, where do I add that in `.vimrc`? Does it come as a standalone line by itself?

Answer (score 4):

You need to open `vimrc` with write permission. In windows it probably would mean opening it as admin.
Also try to do what this message suggests - `:w!` instead of `:w`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding `:w!` or `:w`, where do I add that in `.vimrc`? Does it come as a standalone line by itself?

Comment: @4rleskin. You are right. I may not had an admin permission. I took the file to the desktop, made the changes there, and then returned it back to its original location, ad worked like that.

Comment: I checked :!w and did not know what to do until I found this. :) In the end, I had to open with sudo, thus, the answer gets two points.

Answer (score 3):

The `vimrc` you are editing is not *your* `vimrc`; it is a system-wide `vimrc` that you shouldn't edit *at all*. The correct location for *your* `vimrc` file and `vimfiles` directory on Windows 8 is:

- any Vim version, 7.4 included:

  ```
  <root>\Users\<username>\vimfiles\
  <root>\Users\<username>\_vimrc
  ```
- only 7.4 and up:

  ```
  <root>\Users\<username>\vimfiles\
  <root>\Users\<username>\vimfiles\vimrc
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`_vimrc` was installed in `C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc`. In order to make the changes, I simply had to move the file to the `Desktop` for instance, make the changes, and then override the `_vimrc` file in the original location with this new one.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux users you can try out to **`sudo vim .vimrc`**